# Warning in R using gains() function

Tags: r, rscript

I got this error when trying to use the gains() function in R:

"Warning: Fewer distinct predicted values than groups requested." I used the summary() function to make sure the two data frames I'm trying to compare are of the same size.

Comment: You should include what library gains() is from and show us the coding you're using that results in the warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (num.groups < groups) {  #Just return all distinct scores
       warning("Warning: Fewer distinct predicted values than groups requested")
       pred.group<-rank(-1*predicted,ties.method="min")
    } else if (num.groups == groups)  {  #Just return all distinct scores
       pred.group<-rank(-1*predicted,ties.method="min")
    } else {  
       num.groups<-groups
       pred.rank<-total.n+1-rank(predicted,ties.method=ties.method)
       pred.group<-ceiling(pred.rank/(total.n/groups))    }
```